# Calculate journey time between two locations (co-ordinates) using google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I have co-ordinates of the start and end location. I want to calculate the total time taken to reach the end point. Is there any google maps static api in which i will pass co-ordinates of the start and end location, and in return it will give total time taken to reach the end point from start one ?

An example of google maps static api is something like this :

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C<longitude>,<lat>?&key=<api key>
```

This will return the static map of the given co-ordinates.

Comment: Hi. I think you need to your the Google Directions API instead of the Maps API. See this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) and [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple) example

Comment: It seems like you are right @Pieter-JanBeeckman.. Thank you very much 

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to use [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#traffic-model)

If you have two co-ordinates and you want to know about the total time taken to reach one point, you can do this by passing your co-ordinates as a parameter in this query.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

The response will be a object and in this object there will be all the data that is required for this journey i.e total time, checkpoints, etc

Take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple) example.